# customized grammar similar to json

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to create a grammar that is similar to json but not exactly, the data is like this:

```
{foo=123,bar=abc}
```

basically, names and strings do not have double quotes and equal sign instead of comma for key value seperator, I have the grammar based off the [json v4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/json/JSON.g4) grammar, except I have following modifications:

```
pair
   : STRING '=' value
   ;

value
   : STRING
   |  NUMBER ....;

STRING
    : (ESC | SAFECODEPOINT)+
    ;
```

But parsing above data snippet, the parser will treat the  whol string as a single value, without break it into tokens. I think the problem is STRING definition. How can I fix the STRING token definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your STRING rule is greedy, and doesn't exclude '=' for example, so everything up to the final brace is consumed by that rule.

One way to fix that is to limit what can appear in a field name, e.g. limit to just alphabetic characters. The Antlr grammar shown below does exactly that. You can test it [here](http://lab.antlr.org/). For your sample input:

```
{foo=123,bar=abc}
```

it produces a successful parse tree.

Full grammar:

```
grammar JSON;

json
   : value EOF
   ;

obj
   : '{' pair (',' pair)* '}'
   | '{' '}'
   ;

pair
   : STRING '=' value
   ;

value
   : STRING
   | NUMBER
   | obj
   ;

STRING
   : [a-zA-Z]+
   ;

fragment ESC
   : '\\' (["\\/bfnrt] | UNICODE)
   ;

fragment UNICODE
   : 'u' HEX HEX HEX HEX
   ;

fragment HEX
   : [0-9a-fA-F]
   ;

fragment SAFECODEPOINT
   : ~ ["\\\u0000-\u001F]
   ;

NUMBER
   : '-'? INT ('.' [0-9] +)? EXP?
   ;

fragment INT
   : '0' | [1-9] [0-9]*
   ;

fragment EXP
   : [Ee] [+\-]? [0-9]+
   ;

WS
   : [ \t\n\r] + -> skip
   ;
```